# serilog sinks xamarin tag not visible in log

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, serilog

I'm using serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin as described [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin)

In .Android project I added following code:

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.AndroidLog().Enrich.WithProperty("Tag", "CustomTag").CreateLogger();
```

And calling it from portable class:

```
Log.Information("App is Starting");
```

I can see this line in device log, however tag is blank: 
[missing tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02D3C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Enrich.WithProperty` has to be set to `Constants.SourceContextPropertyName` which in `Serilog` is the constant string of the value: `SourceContext`.

Use "SourceContext" in your `LoggerConfiguration`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.AndroidLog().Enrich.WithProperty("SourceContext", "CustomTag").CreateLogger();
```

In `serilog-sinks-xamarin`, the log TAG is assigned via:

```
var tag = logEvent.Properties.Where(x => x.Key == Constants.SourceContextPropertyName).Select(x => x.Value.ToString("l", null)).FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

re: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin/blob/dec633b488a5c7dd3f3c9a017b972eaf101a177c/src/Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin.Droid/Sinks/Xamarin/AndroidLogSink.cs#L54

re: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/32e0c9578db720add74720bceb62bd46967694c4/src/Serilog/Core/Constants.cs#L27